# Encode URL query parameters

Tags: java, parsing, url, encoding, urlencode

How can I encode URL query parameter values? I need to replace spaces with `%20`, accents, non-ASCII characters etc.

I tried to use `URLEncoder` but it also encodes `/` character and if I give a string encoded with `URLEncoder` to the URL constructor I get a `MalformedURLException` (no protocol).

Comment: Please give some example String and you're code.

Comment: different encoding rules will apply to different [parts of the URI](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/12/java-safe-character-handling-and-url.html#URI2009_ANATOMY). As Lukas suggests, please provide examples of what information you start with and what you want to end up with.

Answer (score 35):

`URLEncoder` has a very **misleading** name. It is according to the [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) used encode form parameters using MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

With this said it can be used to encode e.g., *query parameters*. For instance if a parameter looks like `&/?#` its encoded equivalent can be used as:

```
String url = "http://host.com/?key=" + URLEncoder.encode("&/?#");
```

---

Unless you have those special needs the [URL javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) suggests using [`new URI(..).toURL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which performs URI encoding according to  [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

> The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use URI

The following sample

```
new URI("http", "host.com", "/path/", "key=| ?/#ä", "fragment").toURL();
```

produces the result `http://host.com/path/?key=%7C%20?/%23ä#fragment`. Note how characters such as `?&/` are **not** encoded.

For further information, see the posts [HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java) or [how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java).

---

**EDIT**

Since your input is a string URL, using one of the parameterized constructor of `URI` will not help you. Neither can you use `new URI(strUrl)` directly since it doesn't quote URL parameters.

So at this stage we must use a trick to get what you want:

```
public URL parseUrl(String s) throws Exception {
     URL u = new URL(s);
     return new URI(
            u.getProtocol(), 
            u.getAuthority(), 
            u.getPath(),
            u.getQuery(), 
            u.getRef()).
            toURL();
}
```

Before you can use this routine you have to sanitize your string to ensure it represents an **absolute** URL. I see two approaches to this:

1. Guessing. Prepend `http://` to the string unless it's already present.
2. Construct the URI from a context using [`new URL(URL context, String spec)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: URI uri = new URI("www.google.com");
uri.toURL(); -> exception : "URI is not absolute"

Comment: That's not a [valid URI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). Please use the correct *scheme*, e.g., http.

Comment: @Arutha, that doesn't make it any more right. It means that you have to sanitize the url yourself.

Comment: Nice trick! I'm using it to encode URL's in my Wordnik library now. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't working for me. I've got a url like this: https:/x.com/api/val/?p=q&start=2015-04-30T23:59:59Z&rows=10&page=1 I need the : characters in the query encoded and your transit via a new URL and URI isn't doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

So what you're saying is that you want to encode part of your URL but not the whole thing.  Sounds to me like you'll have to break it up into parts, pass the ones that you want encoded through the encoder, and re-assemble it to get your whole URL.