# Why does the punctuation characters encode UTF 8 while the English characters doesn't?

Tags: java, utf-8, url-encoding

I would like to encode a string to utf-8, the code is:

```
URLEncoder.encode("http://www.example.com/sf?s=191ae04f&an=马赛克.jpg","UTF-8");
```

and the result is:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsf%3Fs%3D191ae04f%26an%3D%C2%ED%C8%FC%BF%CB.jpg
```

as you can see, the punctuation characters,such as `: / ? &`, have been encoded in utf-8, but what result I would like to see is:

```
http://www.example.com/sf?s=191ae04f&an=%C2%ED%C8%FC%BF%CB.jpg
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to URL-encode only the individual components of the URL, such as the query string parameter names/values which may contain characters beyond the ASCII range, not the **entire** URL.

```
String an = URLEncoder.encode("马赛克.jpg", "UTF-8");
String url = "http://www.example.com/sf?s=191ae04f&an=" + an;
// ...
```

Comment: Thanx,i had known that spliting the string would make it, but this way will impose overhead in my application, so, is there any way to convert the entire url into utf-8 without encoding the punctuation characters?

Comment: Parse the URL then. First split on `?`. The left side is the scheme+domain+path. The right side is the query string. The query string is in turn further parseable by splitting on `&`. Every part is the individual parameter `name=value` pair. This is in turn further parseable by splitting on `=`. The left side is the name and the right side is the value. Now you can URL-encode the individual names and values. Finally just glue all the parts together again into a new URL.

Answer (score 1):

You URL-encoded the whole string, so that you can include it in an URL, for example:

```
http://www.yyy.com?forward=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com%2Fsf%3Fs%3D191ae04f%26an%3D%C2%ED%C8%FC%BF%CB.jpg
```

However, what you seem to want is to encode only the parameter values of your original URL. So you have to split the URL, URL-encode only the parameter values, and put it back together again.

Comment: Thanx,i had known that spliting the string would make it, but this way will impose overhead in my application, so, is there any way to convert the entire url into utf-8 without encoding the punctuation characters?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [Java - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198894/java-encode-url), you can use something like

```
public URL parseUrl(String s) throws Exception {
     URL u = new URL(s);
     return new URI(
            u.getProtocol(), 
            u.getAuthority(), 
            u.getPath(),
            u.getQuery(), 
            u.getRef()).
            toURL();
}
```

The reason is that *different* parts of the URL needs to be encoded *differently*.

Alas in your case, the `URLEncoder` should *only* be applied to the **value** of your query parameter.

Answer (score -1):

First thing is you have to encode only the path component of the URL.

The following characters are reserverd characters in URI as per URI specification. Thus URLEncode will escape those characters.

```
":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
```

**Reference:**

[URI Reserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)

Comment: No. URLEncoder is for the name-values pairs in the parameters. Not the path component.