# Parsing a URI with strange characters

Tags: java, parsing, uri

I cannot believe that this has not been addressed in Java YET.

I have seen [Android: howto parse URL String with spaces to URI object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593214/android-howto-parse-url-string-with-spaces-to-uri-object), where the 1st answer represent exactly my problem.

I have a string containing a file location. This can be a file in the system (/...  or c:....) or a URL (http://.....,  ftp://...., etc) If the file is specified in the system or in a URL is **unknown beforehand**.

To distinguish between both I use the

```
new URI(string)
```

and then ask:

```
uri.isAbsolute()
```

This works fine... But guess what - if the path has a space I get an exception!  (java.net.URISyntaxException) So to solve this, what I do is a preliminary:

```
URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");
```

But now, guess what - in case I receive a "http://.." all special characters are replaced, and now the "isAbsolute()" does not recognize it as an absolute URI.

Of course I could do a:

```
 string.replace(" ", "%20")
```

But then... what happens if the name had a strange character different from a space, such as a Chinese or a French character??  Do I have to replace them all myself?  I guess Java SHOULD have something to deal with this situation in a higher level. This is a very common problem, but I was not able to find a proper answer.

Comment: You could always split off the `http://` with a `regex` and then use the `URLEncoder`, then re-add. Not efficient, but it might work.

Comment: Check out this answer, seems to be the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6199056/702568

Comment: Thanks. It seems there is no real solution. I can check if the address has a "http://" but I have to do the same with "ftp://" and many others. This should have been addressed more formally already!  It is strange it is not possible to create a URI if there are spaces or invalid characters (and there is no a pre-established solution - since URLEncoder does not work because it seems to be for another purpose as Kyle pointed out).