# java UTF-8 string

Tags: java, url, utf-8

I want to convert a java string that contains UTF-8 characters to a format that a  browser can use( the string will be used as URL )
What exactly I mean is that url.openStream() cannot open a webpage, when url contains Persian letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `String`s do not contain UTF-8 characters. From the docs for Character:

> The Java 2 platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and StringBuffer classes.

You can use the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class to encode a string so that `url.openStream()` works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the non-ASCII characters in the URL.
See [how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java) and [`URLEncoder#encode(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: So is there a method in Java to do that for me? Thanks