# Encoding a pound sign in a java URI

Tags: java, uri, urlencode

I have a java program that is supposed to read a file from a URL (the URL location is a virtual directory under an IIS web site; below, and in my initial testing, I'm treating it like any other file system location).  Unfortunately the path to all the files that need to be read includes a pound sign (#) in one of the directory names, and there’s nothing I can do to change that.  The program works beautifully when (as a test) I point it to a location that doesn't have that pound sign in the path.

I started by creating a URL from a string passed to the program.  For a file path like `/Documents/#2012/09/11` (where Documents is a Windows share), I could get the program to process successfully if I passed it a path like this on my command line:

```
file://serverIPaddress/Documents/\%232012/09/07/16/DOC4671179.DOC
```

That is, with the pound sign manually encoded as `%23`, and a back slash escaping the % of the %23.

There was just one line to get that URL:

```
URL url = new URL(filePath); // filePath is passed in
```

But the program isn’t going to be spoon-fed an encoded path like that, so I had to figure out how to encode the pound sign programmatically.  Going on the good advice found at [how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java?rq=1), I created a URI using a multi-argument constructor (I broke up the parameter I had been passing to the program into three separate parameters to accommodate that change).  Here’s what that looked like:

```
URI uri = new URI(protocol, host, filePath, null); // all values are passed in
```

That encoded the pound sign properly; my URI was:

```
file://serverIPaddress/Documents/%232012/09/07/16/DOC4671179.DOC
```

But without the backslash in front of the `%23`, the program came back with `Connection refused`, presumably because it’s misinterpreting the path without the benefit of that backslash.

So I thought, ok, I’ll add the backslash myself.  I created the same URI, extracted its rawPath, and with a bit of string manipulation, put a backslash in front of the %23.  I then created a new URI using that new string:

```
URI uri = new URI(protocol, host, filePath, null); // all values are passed in
String rawPath = uri.getRawPath();
int pctPos = rawPath.indexOf("%");
String escaped = new String("\\");
String firstPart = rawPath.substring(0,pctPos);
String secondPart = rawPath.substring(pctPos);
String newPath = firstPart + escaped + secondPart;
URI uri2 = new URI(protocol, host, newPath, null);
```

However, predictably, that gave me a URI like this:

```
file://<serverIPaddress>/Documents/%5C%25232012/09/07/16/DOC4671179.DOC
```

with both the backslash and the % encoded.  Makes sense, but still doesn’t work at execution time.

The URL API says:

> The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components
>   according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the
>   responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be
>   escaped prior to calling URL

So I thought, ok, instead of creating a second URI, I’ll create a URL from that new string I generated in the last try:

```
URI uri = new URI(protocol, host, filePath, null); // all values are passed in
String rawPath = uri.getRawPath();
int pctPos = rawPath.indexOf("%");
String escaped = new String("\\");
String firstPart = rawPath.substring(0,pctPos);
String secondPart = rawPath.substring(pctPos);
String newPath = firstPart + escaped + secondPart;
URL url = new URL(protocol + "://" + host + newPath);
```

But in that approach, even though my new path looked good as:

```
/Documents/\%232012/09/07/16/DOC4671179.DOC
```

the resulting URL comes back as:

```
file://serverIPAddress/Documents//%232012/09/07/16/DOC4671179.DOC
```

with an extra forward slash in front of the %23 instead of a backslash.

And with that I’ve run out of ideas.

- What makes the back slash in this last approach turn into a forward slash in the URL?
- What can I do go get the URI/URL I need?
- Or maybe I should ask: why does the program need the % in the %23 to be escaped in the first place, if that %23 is part of a legitimate URI or URL, and is there something I can do about that instead?

Comment: What are you passing the URL to that gives "connection refused"?

Comment: Some info in this related ServerFault question: http://serverfault.com/q/257680

Comment: nneonneo - Not sure I'm understanding your question.  The program is opening a connection to the URL, getting an InputStream, then an InputStreamReader, then a BufferedReader, and then reading from the file.  The connection refused error comes when trying to get the InputStream.   URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
br = new BufferedReader (isr);

Answer (score 0):

not sure why "\" is required. it depends on server code. actually "\" is not a legal char in URLs, it should be encoded as %5C

`URI` class is pretty messy. It might silently change "\" to "/"  for file URLs.

Try this instead:

```
    String filePath = "/Documents/#2012/09/11";
    filePath = filePath.replace("#", "\\#");
    URI uri = new URI("file", "serverAddress", filePath, null);
```

The "#" will be changed to "%5C%23". see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  As predicted the `replace` gives the URI `file://serverAddress/Documents/%5C%232012/09/11/filename`, but that URI also results in an "IOException: connection refused" error when trying to get the InputStream (after creating a URL from the URI, opening a connection to the URL, etc).

Comment: how about `new URL("file://"+serverAddress+filePath.replace("#", "\\%23")`

Comment: Good idea.  But that also comes back with a URL of `file://172.28.60.68/Documents//%232012/09/11/DOC4671179.DOC` - a forward slash instead of the requested back slash.  There’s something about that class that doesn’t like the back slash.  If the File class will accept a UNC path in its string constructor maybe that will work.  I’m being pulled away by production issues but I’ll try it when I get a moment.

Comment: I gave a copy of the initial version of my java program (the one that creates a URL from a string) to a co-worker who is building the process that will call the program.  He reports that he can call the program successfully by encoding the # to %23 - no backslash.  So I guess we can leave it at that.  For testing from a command line we can call it with \%23, and for calling it programmatically we'll call it with normal encoding.  I would like to know *why* the backslash is necessary from a command line, but I guess we can chalk it up to the command line processor.  Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @user1664369 - by 'command line' I expect you mean as a parameter in a command executed by typing into a shell. In that case you should be aware that `%` is probably a special character. In `bash`, for example, I believe it is _remainder on division_, and it is used as an operator in variable patterns, too. So it needs to be escaped _for the shell_. If you put the entire URI in single quotes in the shell command, you shouldn't need the backslash.