# redirect URL Encoding in web container, response.sendRedirect()

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, web, internationalization

My problem is this, in Java, I have occasion to redirect a user elsewhere, where elsewhere is user definable. The code looks like:

`response.sendRedirect(redirectURL)`.
My focus is on the string represented in the variable redirectURL.
My understanding is this, specifying response.setCharacterEncoding affects the content written to the response writer, not affecting the sendRedirect contents.
It would seem reasonable that by adding URIEncoding= on the connector, in tomcat based containers, should handle the case where the path of a URL is in, simplified Chinese, or Japanese, or non-ascii characters but it  does not. Part of my question is why.

There have been many responses on here stating use URLEncode. However in issue 4571346
[how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java)

Wyzard states that shouldn't be used, rather

1. create a URI object
2. create proper URL string via toASCIIString.

In my for-instance use case, this works fine, albeit this code needs to be performed prior to every `response.sendRedirect()`, which are many.

As more and more applications have global use I see this issue effectively rendering insufficient the straight HTTPResponse method sendRedirect because, by itself, it may not work properly.

I refer all to RFC3490 which deals with Internationalized Domain Names in Applications, which discusses toASCII as one of two operations, the other being toUnicode.

Why, then, does URIEncoding= on the connector, not handle this, should it, and is there a more preferred way to deal with URLs where the path is internationalized?
I just believe, by way of separation of concern, this issue is and should be an container issue, not an application issue. My hope is this will provide a forum for discussion on this issue, not HTML, not forms, not anything other than the URL itself.